# Insert from a list after checking in mysql if duplicate

Tags: python, mysql

From my list, I am looking to insert row by row, but I need to perform a checking before allowing to insert in the database.

let's imagine that is my list

```
unique_hrefs = [
    https://www.linkedin.com/in/123456,
    https://www.linkedin.com/in/789013556,
    https://www.linkedin.com/in/888888888,
    https://www.linkedin.com/in/082b62112,
    https://www.linkedin.com/in/5625a1a,
    https://www.linkedin.com/in/123456,
    https://www.linkedin.com/in/0000000341454,
    https://www.linkedin.com/in/55555555,
    https://www.linkedin.com/in/55555555,
    https://www.linkedin.com/in/66666666,
    https://www.linkedin.com/in/666677777
]
```

I need to check my table for the same string before allowing to inserting and if the string does not exist inserting.
I have my code to inset but struggling to find how to check before inserting it?

```
query= "INSERT INTO name_links (ulr_name) VALUES (%s)
cursor.executemany(query,[(r,) for r in unique_hrefs])
mydb.commit()
```